# How to organize lots of queries in JDBC

Tags: java

my current application requires a myriad of queries, which is extremely hard to maintain. My question is: How would I effectively organize / truncate all of those queries.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
        static MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource ds = BankDataConnection.ds;
        
        static Connection cn;
        static CachedRowSet crs;
    
        static {
    
            try (CachedRowSet newCrs = RowSetProvider.newFactory().createCachedRowSet()) {
    
                cn = ds.getConnection();
    
                crs = newCrs;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
    
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //Used for logins
        static String checkMatchPasswordQuery = "CALL checkMatchPassword(?, ?, ?)";

        static boolean checkMatchPassword(int client_id, String name, String inputPassword) throws SQLException {
            try (CallableStatement cs = cn.prepareCall(checkMatchPasswordQuery)) {

                cs.setInt(1, client_id);
                cs.setString(2, name);
                cs.setString(3, inputPassword);

                ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery();
                rs.next();

                return rs.getBoolean("matched");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return false;
        }

        static String checkNameExist = "CALL checkNameExist(?, ?)";

        protected static boolean checkAccountNameExists(int client_id, String name) throws SQLException {
            try (CallableStatement cs = cn.prepareCall(checkNameExist)) {

                cs.setInt(1, client_id);
                cs.setString(2, name);
        
                ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery();
                rs.next();

                return rs.getBoolean("exist");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return false;
        }

        static String getAccountId = "SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE account_name = ? AND client_id = ?";

        protected static int getAccountId(String name, int client_id) throws SQLException {
            crs.setCommand(getAccountId);
            crs.setString(1, name);
            crs.setInt(2, client_id);

            crs.execute(cn);
            crs.first();

            return crs.getInt("id");
        }
        
        static String getAccountIdLastInserted = "SELECT MAX(id) AS 'lastInsertedID' FROM accounts";

        protected static int getLastInsertedId(String name, String password) throws SQLException {
            crs.setCommand(getAccountIdLastInserted);
            crs.setString(1, name);
            crs.setString(2, password);

            crs.execute(cn);
            crs.first();

            return crs.getInt("lastInsertedID");
        }
```

Note: This is just a small snippet and there are alot more methods than this

Here's also the database's table for convenience:

[image]

My initial guess was that I would need to make a HashMap that stores some kind of BankAccount object with the respective id and handle all "queries" there.

However, this only makes the application less dependant on the database itself, and hardly contribute to the organization as in some methods such as `getAccountId` or `checkAccountNameExists` entail substantial amount of loops.

Comment: Use an ORM instead of manually writing queries?

Comment: Long time ago (20 years) I didn't use an ORM and just coded SQL by hand as you are doing now. Of course when you have 2 or three queries it's simple. However, when you get to the point of having a dozen or more it's different. I used to segregate them in separate classes related to different "modules" or "components". This we would minimize source control collissions when multiple developers were changing/improving/fixing queries at the same time.

Comment: A full blown ORM is not the solution to all database problems. Especially if you already have many working plain JDBC queries. With an ORM, you also get a whole series of disadvantages and peculiarities. The beginning is easy but when it gets complicated, on the one hand you need to know how your ORM is implemented inside and generates SQL. On the other hand, you still need to know SQL well to be able to create reasonably performant queries. You should take a look at MyBatis. This is a thin layer over JDBC and the SQL queries are stored in XML files.

Comment: If you don't want to use MyBatis you can implement a similar system on your own. Store your queries in text files and create a mechanism to get a query by name.

Comment: @Shadow using plain jdbc with manual verified sql statements is tons faster, separates the logic better and can unlease real professional knowledge engeneering. I aggree to use it at the beginning but step by step it should be understood and replaced.

Comment: @LenglBoy whereas I agree with you, the OP seems to have a problem with the approach. If you do not want to bother with manually maintaining a bunch of SQL scripts, then the alternative is ORM.